# Derivative function.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ a,b \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ a<b $. Function is differentiable on $(a,b)$.
Prove the implications :
$1 \Rightarrow 2 $.

1. Function $f $ is unbounded.
2. Function $f'$ is unbounded.

Please for help.

Comment: What in the world is the role of those $\;a<b,\,(0,1)\;$ in your question?? If you don't give more info the claim is false *for general functions*, as $\;f(x)=x\;$ shows.

Comment: I am sorry. I made a mistake.

Comment: @Pa Well, then correct it or else delete your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f'$ is bounded on the open interval $]a,b[$, then there is some $M > 0$ such that $f' \leq M$ on $]a,b[$; so $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x-y| \leq M(b-a)$ for all $x,y \in ]a,b[$ by mean-value theorem. This means that $f$ is bounded on $]a,b[$. For, if $f$ is unbounded then for every $R > 0$ there are some $x,y \in ]a,b[$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| > R$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is to prove that $f'$ bounded implies $f$ bounded. For this, use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: That's exactly what i did.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f'$ bounded by $M $. Then

let $c \in (a,b) $.
we have

$\forall x\in (a,b) $
$f $ continuous at $[c,x]. $

$f $ differentiable at $(c,x) .$

thus by MVT

$$f (x)=f (c)+(x-c)f'(d) $$

with $d\in (c,x) $

we conclude that
$$|f (x)|\leq |f (c)|+|x-c||f'(d)|$$

$$\leq |f (c)|+(b-a)M $$
$f $ is bounded.